# java.lang.StackOverflowError: android.view.View.isLayoutDirectionInherited

Tags: android, view, stack-overflow

Hi i am getting a StackOverflow error while trying to add a view in layout.

Code:

```
parentOfAllInGMT.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.layout_dstbutton, parentOfAllInGMT, true));
```

here parentOfAllInGMT is a Linear Layout and i want `layout_dstbutton` to be the child at index 1.

Prior to adding `layout_dstbutton`, i added

```
parentOfAllInGMT.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.gmt_option_list_dst_on, null, false));
```

which is adding properly.

Following is logcat output:

```
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.View.isLayoutDirectionInherited(View.java:11756)
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5379)
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5380)
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5380)
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5380)
08-06 07:23:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:5380)
```

Comment: How many views do you use in your layout? Try using the hirarchy viewer tool to understand your view hirarchy and try to reduce the ammount of views by relayouting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was design/approach i was taking.

I was using `gmt_option_list_dst_on` which had 34 relative layout, and within each layout i had 5 views. So they all sum up and made a total of 170 views, most probably that was reason reason for stackoverflow exception.

So i choose a customize listview instead of inflating multiple(170) views. Listview allowed me easy way to handle event and performance was enhanced too.